# Como abrir o "Salvar como" em uma aplicação Java?

Tags: java, java-ee

Estou tentando criar uma aplicação que pega um input do usuário armazena em uma variável e salva o input em um diretório informado pelo mesmo através do "salvar como" do windows, porém só consigo acessar o explorador de arquivos e não uma janela de "salvar como" (igual no print), existe alguma forma de fazer isso?

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Runtimetest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String texto = input.nextLine();
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("explorer.exe");
    }
}
```

[image: Salvar como]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O que você está invocando no Runtime executa o "explorer.exe" que nada mais é o explorador de arquivos do Windows mesmo. Geralmente, você envia como parâmetros em qual diretório você deseja salvar o arquivo.

O que você pode fazer é utilizar o Swing e criar sua estrutura usando o File Chooser.

No link abaixo tem uma implementação:

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/DemonstrationofFiledialogboxes.htm